# Amp-carousel work incorrect

Tags: amp-html

When I try to test my webapp in mobile device, `amp-carousel`'s child element `div` with class `-amp-slide-item-show` make something like this:

[image]

In Google dev console in css area of `-amp-slide-item-show` class

```
.-amp-slide-item-show {
display: -webkit-box!important;
/* display: -webkit-flex!important; */
display: -ms-flexbox!important;
/* display: flex!important; */
}
```

I switch off `display: -webkit-flex!important;` and `display: flex!important;` and get it:

[image]

I try to make changes in `<style amp-custom>` tag, and everything is looking good but its not allowed by amp. May be its bug. How can I fixed it? Thnx.

Comment: This issue considered in google groups discuss https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/amphtml-discuss/5ZoSPYH_79U     But I'm not overriding this system classes -amp and i-amp. Have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You might as well double check your html code with [amp-carousel rules](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-carousel/0.1/validator-amp-carousel.protoascii) in the AMP validator specification and there are few sample to compare if your layout is supported.

Comment: As stated in the CSS [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages.html), there are disallowed styles in AMP Pages, it might help to verify your pages in the [AMP validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/). If you feel it is a bug you can [file report](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new), in their git.
Hope it helps!

Comment: AMP Validation successful.

Comment: Сonvertido. I check out my css and drop some excess styles; Thanks for the answers.